# OAuth Access Token request (Twitter API) and oauth_verifier field

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

So, after <s>years</s> days of struggling to get a request_token from `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token` working, I finally successfully generated a Base Signature String and HMAC-SHA1 signature, and received an `oauth_token` from  `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`.

Now, I'm a bit confused about the next step.  My ultimate goal is to be able to simply pull tweets programatically.

I know I need to get an access token from `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token`, but I'm not exactly certain how to proceed.  I know I need to send the `oauth_token` value received by the call to `/oauth/request_token` to `/oauth/access_token`, but I'm conceptually confused by the `oauth_verifier` field in the `Authorization` header.

Most tutorials or documentation regarding this talk in terms of *redirecting the user's browser to a sign-in page*, which is then used to produce a **pin number** for `oauth_verifier`.  But in my case, there is no browser: I'm simply writing an automated daemon in Python that needs to pull certain tweets at regular time intervals.  So there's no browser, and no human "user" involved.  So how does the `oauth_verifier` field apply here?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is [application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth).

Here's an example in **Python 3.3**, of how to obtain the bearer token you can use for application only requests using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) package and assuming the values `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` hold your Twitter API consumer key and secret respectively :

```python
import base64
import requests

# get bearer token for application only requests
bearer_token_credentials = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
    '{}:{}'.format(consumer_key, consumer_secret).encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(bearer_token_credentials),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
}
data = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
response_data = response.json()
if response_data['token_type'] == 'bearer':
    bearer_token = response_data['access_token']
else:
    raise RuntimeError('unexpected token type: {}'.format(response_data['token_type']))
```

The bearer token can then be used to create the authorization headers for your requests like this:

```python
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(bearer_token),
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
}
```